# Ciphers with identical round keys

Tags: block-cipher

Ciphers like [PRINCE](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/529.pdf) or [LED](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/600.pdf) seem to use identical round keys. Does anybody know other cipher (may include hash functions, MACs or AEADs) that has the same property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LED and prince ciphers are designed for lightweight purpose (to save area, energy..etc) , They have no key schedule. Other ciphers that have no key schedule are [Zorro](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/369.pdf), [Midori](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1142.pdf), [LS-designs (Fantomas & Robin)](https://www.iacr.org/archive/fse2014/85400150/85400150.pdf).

The above mentioned ciphers use round constant addition for protection.